# click button every second with countdown

Tags: php, click, seconds

i want click every second example if i click 1 time i can click after 10 second z

```
<form name='form' method='post' >
<input type="submit" id="add" name="help" >
```

Comment: Which type of countdown ? and why you want to autoclick your submit button every second ? Explore more ?

Comment: @SonuR sorry not auto [ if i press one time disable button and enable after 10 second ] and if press do what i type in php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript like below:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
      // form button click on every second
      document.getElementById('add').click();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: sorry but i want click every second example if i click 1 time i can click before 10 second

Answer (score 0):

Try this and add countdown div near to your submit button.

```
<script>
$(function(){
 var countdown = "100" // upto you want
 setInterval(function(){
  countdown--;
 $("#add").trigger("click")
 $("#countdown").html(countdown)

  // you can stop script after you reach to zero
  if(countdown == "0"){
   return false;
   }
 },1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry but i want click every second example if i click 1 time i can click before 10 second

Comment: example i can press every 10 second

Comment: you mean once button clicked, after 10 second only can again click button